# How to run 'mysql' file?

Tags: mysql, docker, circleci, circleci-2.0

In CircleCI **1.0**, we used to have this code:

```
services:
  - mysql

database:
    override:
      - mysql -u ubuntu circle_test < scripts/db/mysql_setup.sql
```

Now we are migrating to **2.0** and mysql is a docker instead of a service:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
      - image: redis:3.2.11
      - image: donilan/mysql-utf8mb4
```

We need to prepare our database, how can I execute this `mysql -u ubuntu circle_test < scripts/db/mysql_setup.sql` when mysql is dockerized?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up connecting to database directly from our app.

There is another approach though (that I was not successful with):

1. Download mysql-client: `apt-get mysql-client`
2. `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root` OR maybe using sockets `mysql -u root`

If anyone is successful, let me know please!